# Attribute Error: Converting hh:mm:ss to decimal in Python

Tags: python, pandas, time

**Solution Update:** From the link provided above, Here's what I've come up with:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('Book1.csv')
df = df.set_index(pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Duration']))
idx = pd.DatetimeIndex(df['Duration'])
df['Duration_Decimal'] = idx.hour + idx.minute / 60
```

**Start of the File**:

```
import pandas as pd
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile
from datetime import datetime

df = pd.read_excel('Book1.xlsx', sheet_name='Sheet1')
```

Here's the column I want to convert:

```
In: df.Duration.head()
Out: 0    01:30:00
     1    00:00:00
     2    00:30:00
     3    00:30:00
     4    00:00:00
     Name: Duration, dtype: object
```

And the function I made:

```
def conversion_function(t):
    (h, m, s) = t.split(':')
    return int(h) + int(m)/60 + int(s)
```

Testing the function:

```
In: conversion_function('01:30:00')
Out: 1.5
```

Insertion of a new column (Duration_2) to the dataframe and execution of conversion_function (with AttributeError):

```
df['Duration_2'] = df['Duration'].apply(conversion_function)
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-4-ad23f30d9b5a> in <module>()
----> 1 df['Duration_2'] = df['Duration'].apply(conversion_function)

D:\Python\lib\site-packages\pandas\core\series.py in apply(self, func, 
convert_dtype, args, **kwds)
   3190             else:
   3191                 values = self.astype(object).values
-> 3192                 mapped = lib.map_infer(values, f, 
                        convert=convert_dtype)
   3193 
   3194         if len(mapped) and isinstance(mapped[0], Series):

pandas/_libs/src\inference.pyx in pandas._libs.lib.map_infer()

<ipython-input-3-d662e6fcae47> in conversion_function(t)
      1 def conversion_function(t):
----> 2     (h, m, s) = t.split(':')
      3     return int(h) + int(m)/60 + int(s)

AttributeError: 'datetime.time' object has no attribute 'split'
```

The function works when I use it on its own, but no matter how many ways I try to tweak it, I just seem to get it to work in the dataframe.

Answer (score 0):

Your data already seem to be in datetime format.  Your `conversion_function` expects to work with strings, though, which is why you get an error (`split()` works on strings).

Since you're working with Pandas, I'd recommend using the built-in Pandas date manipulation methods:

```
data = ["01:30:00", "00:00:00", "00:30:00", "00:30:00", "00:00:00"]
time_data = pd.to_datetime(data)

time_data.hour + time_data.minute / 60
# Float64Index([1.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0], dtype='float64')
```

Note: The error you're getting shows you have the time data in `datetime.time` format - you can also just use the same methods from `datetime.time`, rather than convert to Pandas-specific datetime objects:

```
# match OP's exact time format 
time_data = [datetime.datetime.strptime(x, "%H:%M:%S").time() for x in data]

[x.hour + x.minute/60 for x in time_data]
# [1.5, 0.0, 0.5, 0.5, 0.0]
```

Comment: Reference OP, I've included the solution. ~Regards.